# call function that returns int and store into string c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a string that calls functions and concatenates the return string values. If one of the functions returns an int I get an error. I don't have much experience with overloading operators, but I'm thinking I need to overload the + operator to make this work. Is this correct? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
string str=getString1()+getString2()+getInt();
```

Comment: You can use getInt().ToString() to convert the integer to a string.

Comment: @dubstylee: Did you test that, or are you just making stuff up?

Comment: @KerrekSB He may have mistaken the question for C#, though IIRC `ToString()` is called implicitly in this situation in C#.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice C++ before I posted my comment.

Comment: Use [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert numeric values perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/).

```
string str = getString1() + getString2() + std::to_string(getInt());
```

Comment: I'm getting the error more than one instance of overloaded function "to_string" matches the argument list

Comment: @Jordan, If I remember correctly, that was fixed in a later version of VS.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the type cast _ULonglong. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::to_string` as suggested by vincent you could also overload the `+` operator in an easy way:

```
// string + int
std::string operator+(const std::string &str, const int &i){
    std::string result = str + std::to_string(i);
    return result;
}
// int + string
std::string operator+(const int &i, const std::string &str){
    std::string result = std::to_string(i) + str;
    return result;
}
```

Then your original code should work as espected.

```
string str = getString1() + getString2() + getInt();
```

Example:

```
td::cout << string("This is a number: ") + 5 << endl;
std::cout << 5 + string(" is a number.") << endl;
```

Output:

```
This is a number: 5
5 is a number.
```